# When set AUTO_READ = false, the netty lost some data

Tags: netty

I tried to implement backpressure by invoking channel.read() manually. But it seems client will miss some data.

**Example**:
Server sends an incremental integer per 1s, and print the integer.
Client read from the socket per 5s, then writes the integer to console log.

**Result**
Server side:

```
Mon Nov 25 00:22:48 CST 2019 write to socket: 1 channel : [id: 0x2aba8985, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 - R:/127.0.0.1:65361]
write to socket successfully 1
Mon Nov 25 00:22:49 CST 2019 write to socket: 2 channel : [id: 0x2aba8985, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 - R:/127.0.0.1:65361]
write to socket successfully 2
Mon Nov 25 00:22:50 CST 2019 write to socket: 3 channel : [id: 0x2aba8985, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 - R:/127.0.0.1:65361]
write to socket successfully 3
Mon Nov 25 00:22:51 CST 2019 write to socket: 4 channel : [id: 0x2aba8985, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 - R:/127.0.0.1:65361]
write to socket successfully 4
Mon Nov 25 00:22:52 CST 2019 write to socket: 5 channel : [id: 0x2aba8985, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 - R:/127.0.0.1:65361]
write to socket successfully 5
Mon Nov 25 00:22:53 CST 2019 write to socket: 6 channel : [id: 0x2aba8985, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 - R:/127.0.0.1:65361]
write to socket successfully 6
Mon Nov 25 00:22:55 CST 2019 write to socket: 7 channel : [id: 0x2aba8985, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 - R:/127.0.0.1:65361]
write to socket successfully 7
Mon Nov 25 00:22:56 CST 2019 write to socket: 8 channel : [id: 0x2aba8985, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 - R:/127.0.0.1:65361]
write to socket successfully 8
Mon Nov 25 00:22:57 CST 2019 write to socket: 9 channel : [id: 0x2aba8985, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 - R:/127.0.0.1:65361]
write to socket successfully 9
Mon Nov 25 00:22:58 CST 2019 write to socket: 10 channel : [id: 0x2aba8985, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 - R:/127.0.0.1:65361]
write to socket successfully 10
Mon Nov 25 00:22:59 CST 2019 write to socket: 11 channel : [id: 0x2aba8985, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 - R:/127.0.0.1:65361]
write to socket successfully 11
```

Client Side:

```
Mon Nov 25 00:22:47 CST 2019 received signal: 0
Mon Nov 25 00:22:52 CST 2019 received signal: 1
Mon Nov 25 00:22:57 CST 2019 received signal: 5
Mon Nov 25 00:23:02 CST 2019 received signal: 10
Mon Nov 25 00:23:07 CST 2019 received signal: 15
Mon Nov 25 00:23:12 CST 2019 received signal: 20
```

**Question**:
The socket read buffer doesn't exceed at the client side, but it missed the number 2/3/4/6/7/8/9/...

Where these number gone?

You can replay the case easily with the test case: [link](https://github.com/zman2013/net-pull)
The `server` code: [link](https://github.com/zman2013/net-pull/blob/master/src/test/java/server/NettyServer.java)
The `client` code: [link](https://github.com/zman2013/net-pull/blob/master/src/test/java/client/NettyClient.java)

Answer (score 0):

@ninja- figured what the hell happened here...

The root cause is I didn't drain the buffer in channelRead, just read the head four bytes instead.

By adding following code, this issue was fixed.

```java
int readableBytesSize = buf.readableBytes();

while( readableBytesSize/4 > 0 ) {
    int signal = buf.readInt();
    System.out.println(new Date()
            + " received signal: "
            + signal);
    readableBytesSize -= 4;
}
```

github issue: [link](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/9793)